# iPad Apple keyboard error message

Tags: ipad, keyboard

[image]

I have the iPad Pro 12", original model (when it first came out), along with the Apple keyboard/cover. 
This error message appears randomly, and searches so far have blamed it on an OS update, but those notes are from a few revisions back. The current iOS is what I've installed 11.3.1 and the error still occurs, making the iPad virtually unusable even using this as a cover, not even typing. Any hacks/fixes to this issue?

Comment: Does the error occur even when the cover is _not_ attached to the iPad? (As a side note: having had occasion to test out the original 12" iPad Pro, keyboard/cover & pencil for a few months, I thought to myself then that the cover/keyboard, although durable and well constructed, would prove to be the weak link in the device triad over time.)

Comment: Thx. No. The message has never come up with no cover on. With the cover being an Apple branded item, I thought they’d fix this issue by now. Very random, but frequent, and I don’t use the keyboard too often anyway.

Comment: It may be a faulty or physically damaged keyboard then. Are the contacts on the connector edge of the keyboard clean and crud-free?

Comment: No, shiny clean connectors.